# source command not found

Tags: ros, source, setup.sh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to install ros on my ubuntu 11.10 and get it work. I followed successfully the tutorial here http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu and I'm attempting to the following one here : http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment. According to the second instruction I went to setup.sh which is in /opt/ros/electric/ and modified it according to the script written in that page. But when I run source setup.sh, I get the error " /opt/ros/electric/setup.sh: 2: source: not found " .I tried to change  #!/bin/sh by  #!/bin/bash in the beginning of the setup.sh and ran bash /opt/ros/electric/setup.sh but I'm still getting the same error

Thank you in advance for your help

Rim Zahir

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12345/source-command-not-found/) by [rimzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/1536/rimzahir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-12-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-12-14**:
It would probably help if you posted your edited setup.sh file. Perhaps somewhere like http://beta.pastee.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
According to
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment
you are not supposed to edit the setup.sh file in the "/opt/ros/electric/" path but setup in your ros_workspace folder created by you.
The idea behind setting up the workspace is to have the packages fetched by ros automatically.
Once you download or create a package in this workspace in the future, the ros commands like roscd, rosmake, rosed etc would be able to lookup in this path.
Once you setup the environment/workspace, your

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

would give the following output

```
/home/user/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks
```

You have to source this path to your ~/.bashrc file so that it gets picked up every time you run the terminal.

Hope this helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rimzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/1536/rimzahir/) on 2011-12-22**:
Thanks for your help

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-14**:
yes just follow the tutorial. replace ~/ros_workspace this with your own workspace path in all the places.

**Comment by [rimzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/1536/rimzahir/) on 2011-12-14**:
Thank you for answering that quickly. I set the setup.sh file back as it was (i changed only the first line so it was easy). You said that I have to setup setup.sh in ros_worspace, does that mean I have to create the setup.sh with the script provided in the website in ros_workspace?